# Access multiple graphs from neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I want to move virtuoso to neo4j. I have total three different graphs(Databases). Can I access multiple graphs from one neo4j server. virtuoso server provides this functionality. I read [Storing multiple graphs in Neo4J question asked in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957907/storing-multiple-graphs-in-neo4j) so i would like to know that neo4j server provides this functionality or not?

Thanking You in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really the direct answer to your question regarding Neo4j's capabilities, but I thought I would offer the [TinkerPop](http://tinkerpop.com) option.  If your system can support it from a resources perspective, you could host multiple separate Neo4j instances inside a single [Rexster](http://rexster.tinkerpop.com) instance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that a neo4j instance only has one 'database' per instance- all the data is in the same folder.  That said, there is nothing from storing multiple unconnected graphs within the same neo4j instance.  If you keep the labels and relationship types separate - they'll never interact - you just would have to keep it in mind with your cypher queries, but you would at least be *able* to do cross graphspace queries if needed.

Alternately, you could run multiple instances of neo4j, each on a different port, pointing at a different data directory, but you would lose any cross-instance visibility.